# Untimeout in DMS

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Is there a way to `Untimeout` a user from `dms`?

i tried using this code:

```
@bot.command()
async def untimeout(ctx, user: discord.Member, guild_id: int):
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    if guild:
        try:
            await user.untimeout()
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.reply(f"ERROR: {e}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Guild not found.")
```

Comment: If you want to remove the timout on a member in a **Guild** (not in dms) you can use `user.timeout(until=None)`.
You can't timeout a user in Direct Message, but you can timeout a Member in a Guild, see [the documentation here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.timeout).
User != Member, *a Member is a User in a Guild*.

Comment: so even if you have a guild id you cant untimeout someone in dms?

Comment: What do you mean by "dms", the only way you can timeout someone is inside a Guild (in a discord server). You can't timeout a User in Direct Message (Private message).

Comment: direct messages so if you DM the bot !untimeout {TIMEDOUTUSER} {GUILDID} they get untimedout in the guild

Answer (score 0):

## Untimeout a discord.User from Direct Message

---

To untimeout a user from DMs in Discord, first fetch the guild, then retrieve the member from that guild, and finally untimeout the user.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def untimeout(ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.User, guild_id: int):
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id) # 1. get the guild
    if guild:
        member = guild.get_member(user.id) # 2. get the member
        if member:
            await member.timeout(None) # 3. untimeout
            await ctx.reply("The user has been untimed out")
        else:
            await ctx.reply("User not found")
    else:
        await ctx.reply("Guild not found")
```

To test this command type the following: `untimeout <@user_id_here> guild_id_here`

---

To simplify the command and make it more convenient, we can replace two parts of our code:

- `user_id`

```py
async def untimeout(ctx: commands.Context, user_id: int, guild_id: int) -> None:
```

- `member`

```py
member = guild.get_member(user_id)
```

With these changes, users can now use the command: `untimeout user_id_here guild_id_here`